# preventing page from creating additional dialogs not binding the angular js properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I have a simple code where there are 3 consecutive alert messages ;
after which I bind the view using `{ { } }`
but when I preventing page from creating additional dialogs, the binding part does not work, why is it happening 
[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gMkLjwBeMzeDggmoP7KT?p=preview)
I created a link when I permit the alerts always everything is fine.

I find the code working in chrome I am testing it with firefox .

Thank you.

Comment: it is working fine or I did not get the question...

Comment: its not working fine when I prevent page from creating additional dialogs

Comment: I prevent it as well but it is still working...

Comment: no for me its not working for firefox try it in plunker

Comment: I have 3 alert () when I prevent 2nd alert the data is not binding properly

Comment: it is working in chrome maybe you should add this information to your question...

Comment: @wickY26 I am checking in firefox just added the info in edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This error is mostly specific to Gecko (Firefox, Mozilla) because it
>   adheres to those specs closer to the letter in this regard.

for more [information](http://helpful.knobs-dials.com/index.php/0x80004005_%28NS_ERROR_FAILURE%29_and_other_firefox_errors) about this error...

easiest solution of this problem is wrapping code into try-catch block...

```
    try {
      alert("d");
      alert("d");
      alert("d");
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("error catched", e);
    }
```

here is your updated [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/V2pQSW6GEFvVM1cICUMK?p=preview)...